# Modal bootstrap help does not work with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a small project for class, which does not insert the data to the database, the data I collect with a bootstrap modal and pass them to the php file using ajax. The error comes at the time of using the script, I think it is correct, but I do not execute the actions.

This is the script I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){      
        $('#confirm').click(function() {
          var tk =  $("#task").val();
          var dt = $("#date").val();
          var at = $("#amount").val();
          var st = $("#status").val();

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: {"task": tk, "date": dt, "amount": at, "status": st},
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#task").val("");
                $("#date").val("");
                $("#amount").val("");
                $("#status").val("");
            }
          });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New task</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="task_insert">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Task:</label>
                    <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="task">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Date:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" required type="text" id="date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Amount:</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" required id="amount">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Status:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="status" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="confirm" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to everyone for your support

Comment: have you checked your console if there's any error? and put a debug in `$('#confirm').click(function() {` to see if it's working or not second have you added jquery in that page where you write your script?

Comment: and where is your server script?

Comment: I have added jquery using<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can I see your `insert.php` and error which you can see in console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help You

add jquery at top of page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

then write your ajax script and get your value in insert.php page like:

$task = $_POST['task'];

echo $task;

if still not work then take form inside modal and submit form using jquery.